# Unable to start Windows Service that hosts WCF service with NetNamedPipeBinding binding

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services, netnamedpipebinding

I am creating a windows service that is supposed to host a WCF service with **NetNamedPipeBinding** binding. Following is the code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var serviceType = typeof(IServeHi);

    var namedPipeBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
    namedPipeBinding.Security.Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None;
    var namedPipeEndpoint = "";

    var baseNamedPipeUri = new Uri("net.pipe://MyWorkstation:51301/"); // Line # 41

    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServeHi), baseNamedPipeUri);

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, namedPipeBinding, namedPipeEndpoint);

    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true});
    host.Open();
}
```

The `installutil.exe` is able to successfully install it. However, when I try to start the service, I get a message ***The WindowsServiceHost1 on a Local Computer started and then stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs***.

Further, the Windows Log reads as:

```
Service cannot be started. System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at WindowsServiceHost1.WindowsServiceHost1.OnStart(String[] args) in C:\WindowsServiceHost1\Service1.cs:line 41
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

I have tried **WSHttpBinding** & **NetTcpBinding** and they work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to remove the port number from the net.pipe URI. Try changing line 41 to:

```
var baseNamedPipeUri = new Uri("net.pipe://MyWorkstation/");
```

or if you need a more descriptive pipe name:

```
var baseNamedPipeUri = new Uri("net.pipe://MyWorkstation_51301/");
```

[This blog post](http://bgottschall.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/system-uri-can-parse-namedpipe-net-pipe-urls/) has some helpful insight on this issue.